# How to install XCode 4.5GM on top of the app store xcode 4.4.1?

Tags: ios, xcode

I was searching for the answer to this question here but couldn't find anything.  I had an issue before with GM version of xcode and would like to find out what is the procedure to do this. I have XCode 4.4.1 install from the app store and i would like to install 4.5 GM.  Is the only way to have both installed on the machine or its possible to upgrade? Does it make sense to delete 4.4.1 and install GM version or just wait a week and xcode will get updated automatically.

I just don't want to install this one and then have to reinstall when the app store version comes out because then upgrades will be installed through the app store.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the AppStore version (4.4.1) and the beta version (4.5) side by side without any problems. Just download the beta from the developer portal and it will install as "Xcode45-GM".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have 4.4.1 installed already i was wondering if it make sense to install 4.5 now or wait.  What happens when the app store gets the update then i can delete the GM version and update 4.4.1 through the store?

Comment: Also can i open project in both 4.4.1 and 4.5GM with out an issue?

Comment: I think i got it.  I didn't realize it's just one file that i can rename as you said and copy into the application folder.  If anything i can always delete it to uninstall.  I remember from before had to run some terminal command to delete all xcode from the mac.  Thanks!

Comment: You can switch back and forth without a problem, yes.

Comment: I am updating the app store version of xcode to 4.5 right now.  After it is done i can delete the GM version and open the files in the app store version?  Thanks!